# Elemental functions cannot be pointed to by procedure pointers

Tags: function, pointers, fortran, procedure

I'm trying to use a procedure pointer (new feature in Fortran 2003) to point to an elemental function but it does not work. I really need the function to be `ELEMENTAL` and need a pointer to it. Is it truly impossible to point to an elemental function in Fortran?

```
    module elemfunc
    implicit none

    contains
        elemental function fun111(x) result(y)
        real*8, intent(in) :: x
        real*8 :: y 

            y = x**2+1

        end function fun111
    end module elemfunc


    program testptr
    use elemfunc
    implicit none

      interface
        elemental function func (z)
        real*8 :: func
        real*8, intent (in) :: z
        end function func
      end interface

        procedure (func), pointer :: ptr
        ptr => fun111

        print *, ptr( (/1.0d0,2.0d0/) )

    end program testptr
```

Error message:

```
main.f90:12.7:ptr=>fun111
                     1
Nonintrinstic elemental procedure pointer 'func111' is invalid in procedure pointer assignment at (1)
```

Comment: FWIW your code compiles and executes (apparently) correctly for me.  I'm using Intel Fortran 13.1.0.149. Even if I crank warnings and syntax-checking up to 11 the compiler issues no complaints. I can't say that I am certain that your code is standard-compliant, but I can't see that it isn't either.

Comment: Amazing!I'm using gfortran 4.7(not for sure...). Perhaps I should update my gfortran???

Comment: @High Performance Mark see [NewFeatureFortran2003](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1551-N1600/N1579.pdf), seach 'elemental', the first matching result says that elemental INTERFACE is not permitted, but I dont know whether it is same with elemental FUNCTIONS...

Comment: Newest gfortran 4.8 produces the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In paragraph `7.4.2 Pointer Assignment` of the fortran 2003 standard it is explicitly stated that this is not allowed:

```
C728 (R742) The proc-target shall not be a nonintrinsic elemental procedure
```

(This constraint is still there in the fortran 2008 standard, so it hasn't been relaxed.)

Comment: Yes, it is the same constraint the OP quotes in his comment.

Comment: @VladimirF: Ah, I hadn't looked at that. So it appears the OP already knew the answer to his question.

Comment: Thank you all. The constraint really makes me sad...!_!....I have to rewrite my codes all again without using elemental functions

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same issue and did not even realize it was an issue until I compiled with gfortran. Unfortunately, it is also forbidden to have dummy procedure arguments to elemental procedures. It is, however, still possible to achieve the functionality you want, though it is a bit kludgy.

What you can legally do is have an elemental function call a pure function. Depending on your needs, the elemental function can be type bound or not.

#### Option one

Put the procedure pointer and function inside a module:

```
module A
  implicit none

  procedure(func_IF), pointer :: ptr => null()

  abstract interface
    pure function func_IF(x)
      real, intent(in) :: x
      real :: func_IF
    end function
  end interface
contains
  ! Non type bound elemental
  elemental function myfun1(x) result(r)
    real, intent(in) :: x
    real :: r    
    if(associated(ptr)) r = ptr(x)
  end function
end module
```

#### Option two

Put both pointer and function inside a derived type:

```
module B
  implicit none

  type :: foo
    procedure(func_IF), nopass, pointer :: ptr => null()
  contains
    procedure, pass :: myfun2
  end type

  abstract interface
    pure function func_IF(x)
      real, intent(in) :: x
      real :: func_IF
    end function
  end interface
contains
  ! Type bound elemental
  elemental function myfun2(this, x) result(r)
    class(foo), intent(in) :: this
    real, intent(in) :: x
    real :: r    
    if(associated(this%ptr)) r = this%ptr(x)
  end function
end module
```

A small test program:

```
program main
  use A
  use B
  implicit none

  type(foo) :: myfoo
  myfoo%ptr => bar
  ptr => bar

  print*, myfun1([10., 20.])
  print*, myfoo%myfun2([10., 20.])
contains
  ! Demo pure function with interface func_IF
  pure function bar(x)
    real, intent(in)    :: x
    real                :: bar
    bar = x**2
  end function
end
```